# Java equivalent to PHP's multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create "anonymous" arrays of datas, with non-numeric keys, the same way I could do it in PHP, just like that :

```
$datas = [
    [
        'firstname' => 'Sam',
        'lastname' => 'Winchester',
        'job' => 'Hunter',
        'age' => 30
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Dean',
        'lastname' => 'Winchester',
        'job' => 'Hunter',
        'age' => 35
    ],
];
```

I'd like to know if I can do that without creating a specific class or something like that.

I found some solutions using maps but it's only working with 2 fields, not more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in Java. You would have to create a class `Person` with 4 fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `job` and `age`, and then use a `Person[]`.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Boddington 's answer is great too but if you want to have a more general solution, you could create a list of hashmaps.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>(); // Diamond expression
List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); // non diamond
```

Adding your data of your PHP array into our solution

```
HashMap<String, String> personOne = new HashMap<String, String>();
personOne.put("firstname", "Sam");
personOne.put("lastname", "Winchester");
...
data.add(personOne);
```

Voila.

Comment: I'm afraid that it wouldn't work since I have different types for each field, such as `int` for the `age` field.

Comment: @AntoineB for dealing with different types of data just declare them as Object like this: `HashMap<Object, Object>`